# command doesn't work on SSH , Terminal works

Tags: command-line, ssh

starnge problem 
I want to run a command in SSH

```
export DISPLAY=:0;xset q;
```

when I run it on terminal - its working 
when I enter the ubuntu using ssh (with the same user\pass) it doesn't work 
This is what I get :

> Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyxset:  unable to open display ":0"

Why is it?
and how to fix this?

Thanks ,

Comment: Fix in what sense? `xset q` shows the current user preferences for the X session. What do you expect it to show when you are connected through SSH?

Comment: the all xset setting (like when I connect in terminal).                                            also I have notice that when I use 'env' in ssh and 'env' in terminal i don;t see the same variables - I guess this is the problem?

Comment: The question is _what settings_, local or remote? Why would you care about the settings of the user who may or may not have an X session open on the remote machine?

Comment: never mind - find how to do this , I'm running at startup the command and then when i enter in ssh it's work