# How to force a remote server to wake up its monitor using SSH?

Tags: 16.04, server, ssh, suspend, power-management

If the monitor on a remote Ubuntu Server goes into sleep mode, is there a way that you can wake it up from an SSH command line?

I have tried using `export "DISPLAY=:0"` and then `xset -dpms` to try and turn off power saving modes but I get:

```
 Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyxset:  unable to open display ":0"
```

The server is Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS running the Zentyal web front end. There is a UI on the remote server that local admins can log into, but for some unknown reason after applying updates via the Zentyal web admin screen and re-booting the screen seems to go into power save and wiggling the mouse or pressing a key won't wake it so I am trying to force the server to wake up the screen.

Comment: *Did you try plugging it out and in again?* Seriously, did you try `xrandr --output YOURSCREEN --off && xrandr --output YOURSCREEN --auto`? You did run `xset` as root, didn't you?

Comment: Did you try to set the display directly in `xset`? `xset -display :0 -dpms`

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/854246/command-doesnt-work-on-ssh-terminal-works and https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2220583

Comment: @dessert I am remote to the site that has the server so I asked them to wiggle the mouse and press a shift key on the server's keyboard and that did not work. The screen just reports that it is in power save mode. I didn't run xset as root or use sudo and I did not run xrandr.

Comment: @dessert I did try running xset -display using two separate commands, ie:

Comment: export "DISPLAY=:0" then xset -dpms as per my question and that's when I get the "unable to open display ":0" error message. I will try and run it the way you have put it.

Comment: @dessert - Still same error when using:

xset -display :0 -dpms

Comment: Also same error when using sudo.

Comment: @dessert - are you assuming I am on a terminal on the server or are you aware I am doing this using ssh remotely?

Comment: I am aware of that, but out of ideas for now.

Comment: @dessert my question was more about waking the monitor than the things I had tried being wrong, I was hoping someone like you with more knowledge could point me at some subsystem like power saving that I could configure so that it was in a "no power saving" mode?

Comment: OK, let's see: You could (carefully!) play around with the settings for the monitor in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`, especially `Option "DPMS" "0"` could be helpful. See `man xorg.conf`'s `MONITOR SECTION` for more.

Comment: When I list the contents of /etc/X11 I see this:
app-defaults             openbox  xkb       Xresources  Xsession.options
default-display-manager  rgb.txt  Xreset    Xsession    xsm
fonts                    xinit    Xreset.d  Xsession.d

but no xorg.conf?  Could this be because Zentyal changes the locations of the X files?

Comment: Please consult `man xorg.conf`'s `DESCRIPTION` section for the whole list where `xorg.conf` can be located.

Comment: I did "sudo find / -name Xorg.conf" and it came back with no results? So it would appear I have no Xorg.conf? Also did same for xorg.conf and no joy either unless I am getting the find command wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this thread is old, but just in case someone is wondering. I was getting exactly the same problem:
unable to open display ":0"

I was trying to turn on two of my displays via SSH, but it failed with the message from above. Other thing I had to say is that I wasn't logged on the console of the physical PC, so, only the logon screen was there, but the displays were off because of the idle settings.

So, on my case, I had to add also the XAUTHORITY variable as follows:

```
#Turn on the main display
sudo DISPLAY=:0 XAUTHORITY=/run/user/121/gdm/Xauthority xrandr --output HDMI-0 --off
sudo DISPLAY=:0 XAUTHORITY=/run/user/121/gdm/Xauthority xrandr --output HDMI-0 --auto

#Turn on the second display
sudo DISPLAY=:0 XAUTHORITY=/run/user/121/gdm/Xauthority xrandr --output DP-4 --right-of HDMI-0 --off
sudo DISPLAY=:0 XAUTHORITY=/run/user/121/gdm/Xauthority xrandr --output DP-4 --right-of HDMI-0 --auto
```

Here I have to mention that I'm using Ubuntu 18 with gdm3 as display manager. You should check the path:

```
/run/user/121/gdm/Xauthority
```

It maybe different on your system. Also check your xorg.conf configuration. There I defined two screens as follows:

```
    Screen      0  "Screen0"
    Screen      1  "Screen1" RightOf "Screen0"
```

That's why I'm using the "--right-of" option.

Finally check the names of your ouputs by running:

```
sudo DISPLAY=:0 XAUTHORITY=/run/user/121/gdm/Xauthority xrandr -q
```

There you will get the right names. On my case: "HDMI-0" (main monitor) and "DP-4" (second monitor).

Comment: Thanks for your comment, this was a long time ago and I got sick of Zentyal and the HP Server it was running on causing problems like this so now we have a Dell Server running ClearOS and everything works like a charm, so I don't need to fix it any more, however I have this page bookmarked and if I hit this issue in the future I will at least know how to fix it.

Thanks again.